# Shut-off valve fitting waxed hemp vs unwaxed hemp vs teflon tape?

Tags: plumbing, valve

EDIT: Or some of those combinated?

What is the best method and why, and what is the proper way to apply?

Answer (score 2):

Hemp is natural fiber will last but adding wax helps to lubricate and will last longer , for the longest lasting valve stem packing I use PFTE. PFTE rope not tape although tape will work with enough wraps the "rope" comes in different sizes, PFTE won't freeze like hemp that has some water in it, PFTE in a powered form is a great lubricant where hemp can be a bit abrasive over the years. Both are goodproducts but I would use Teflon over hemp and the best option would be the rope or round PFTE products tape will work but it takes a lot of wraps.

Comment: I tried using teflon, and I am not sure if I am using the correct amount, but I did a lot of wraps (over 8) and it was still loose on every thread joint I tried. 

I watched some videos, most of them say 3-6 wraps max, not sure if their tapes are thicker, mine is very thin, but what do you recommend? I can only find PFTE tape and hemp tho. If I lastly choose to go hemp route, what kind of wax should I get (if there are types)?

Comment: Using this as a valve stem packing it may take 30+ wraps you have to build it up enough for the cap to squeeze it. 3-6 wraps is for threads hemp would not work there.

Comment: sorry for my confusious write, I am asking for an undersink shut-off water valve,  should I just try as many wraps up until it starts to have a decent amount of pressure even on the second rotation when I will be screwing the valve in?

Comment: So I am not sure where your leak is if it is coming out of the valve stem the nut needs to be removed usually with the main water supply turned off. Wrap the Teflon around the stem until it is about 1/8" thick then put the nut back on and tighten the nut. Most hardware stores have valve stem packing kits of Teflon rope some are black in color several inches long, wrap around the stem place the nut on and tighten. This can repair a leaking stem. If the fitting is leaking many times it has been over tightened and the line needs to be replaced.

Comment: there is no leak nor nut, I am currently setting it up and the valve screws in like a screw to a threaded pump end. So around 18 times?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking since the explanation has changed a couple times, however, if you are asking about the use of teflon tape or a form of pipe dope for the threads, Try this; use 3-4 teflon tape wraps in the direction of the threads on the valve and then cover the teflon tape with a coating of RTV silicone. Screw the fittings together and let it stand over night before running water. More than 3-4 wraps does not a good joint make.  If you are speaking of packing for a valve stem, almost anything will work. I have used string, teflon packing, waxed hemp, graphite cord, even a large piece of teflon tape doubled over 2-3 times and twisted into rope. If a leak is still present, replace the leaking items.